# How to i render my detected URL to a hyperlink instead of plain text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, socket.io, mustache

I'm working on a chat application where users can message each other. I have used the anchorme library to detect links / URLs / Emails in text and convert them to clickable HTML which it does. But the detected URLs are not clickable it is just converted as plain
text. Is there a way to convert it to a hyperlink?[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css">
 </head>
     <body>
     <div class="chat">
         <div id="sidebar" class="chat__sidebar">
 
         </div>
         <div class="chat__main">
             <div id="messages" class="chat__messages"></div>
 
             <div class="compose">
                 <form id="message-form">
                     <input name="msg" placeholder="Message" required autocomplete="off">
                     <button>Send message</button>
                 </form>
                 <button id="send-location">Send location</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <script id="message-template" type="text/html">
         <div class="message">
             <p>
                 <span class="message__name">{{username}}</span>
                 <span class="message__meta">{{createdAt}}</span>
             </p>
             <p>{{message}}</p>
         </div>
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.6.0/qs.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/chat.js"></script>
     <script src="https://raw.githack.com/alexcorvi/anchorme.js/gh-pages/dist/browser/anchorme.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Javascript client side:

```
 const socket = io()
     
     //Elements
     const msg = document.querySelector('#message-form')
     const messageFormInput = msg.querySelector('input')
     const messageFormButton = msg.querySelector('button')
     
     //Templates
     const messages = document.querySelector("#messages")
     const messageTemplate = document.querySelector('#message-template').innerHTML
     
     
     
     //ref to index.js 
     socket.on('message', (message) => {
         const html = Mustache.render(messageTemplate, {
             //will come from the value
             username: message.username,
             message: message.text,
             createdAt: moment(message.createdAt).format('HH:mm')
         })
         messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
         scrollAuto()
     })
     
     //Refers to html form input
     msg.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
         //Prevents browser to update
         e.preventDefault()
     
         messageFormButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
     
         const message = e.target.elements.msg.value
         socket.emit('sendMsg', message, (error) => {
             messageFormButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
             messageFormInput.value = ''
             messageFormInput.focus()
             //Enable after event acknowledged
     
             if (error) {
                 return console.log(error)
             }
         })
     })
     
     socket.emit('join', {
         username,
         room
     }, (error) => {
         if (error) {
             alert(error)
             location.href = '/'
         }
 
     })
```

Javascript server:

```
     const path = require('path')
     const http = require('http')
     const express = require('express')
     const socketio = require('socket.io')
     
     //Destructuring
     const {
         generateMessage,
     } = require('./utils/messages')
     
     // Convert Urls
     const anchorme = require("anchorme").default;
     // Check for profanity
     const Filter = require('bad-words')
     //Initiate socket-io
     const io = socketio(server)
     
     // Define path for Express config 
     const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
     app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
     
     //Server-side
     io.on('connection', (socket) => {
         console.log(' WebSocket Connection')
     
         // Listening for socket i.e messages
         socket.on('sendMsg', (message, callback) => {
             const user = getUser(socket.id)
     
             var result = anchorme(message, {
                 attributes: [{
                     name: "target",
                     value: "_blank"
                 }, ]
             });
             console.log(result)
     
             var filter = new Filter()
             if (filter.isProfane(message)) {
                 return callback('Profanity is not allowed')
             }
             io.to(user.room).emit('message', generateMessage(user.username, result))
             callback()
         })
     })

const generateMessage = (username, text) => {
     return {
         username,
         text,
         createdAt: new Date().getTime()
     } }
```

Comment: Did you try to add type="text/html" to the <p> that contains the message ?

Comment: I've tried still same result

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using React to render the message component.  By default, React treats all HTML as text.  They have a method called [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), which is aptly named. It's not a good idea to allow users to send HTML or any other code for security reasons. Although, if you're generating the HTML, it should be safe for you to use this method.

Comment: Thanks!, are there any other methods I can use to solve this, or is dangerouslySetInnerHTML method the only way in this case.